# How do you setup heroku for another owner's app?

Tags: git, heroku

My friend released our staging environment to heroku and gave me permission to release as well.  However, I am not sure how to setup an existing heroku app, in order to merge my dev branch into staging and then release it?

For example,

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:SC/SCTest.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:SC/SCTest.git (push)
staging git@heroku.com:robot-6850.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:robot-6850.git (push)
$ git branch -v
* master ec8c252 survey finalize
```

So, essentially, I would like to 1) map the 'staging' remote to a local branch of mine, 2) merge my dev branch 'origin' into 'staging' and 3) release 'staging' again but am not really sure how to do this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work in your local 'dev' branch locally.

When you are ready to deploy merge this branch into your staging branch and then deploy your staging branch to your heroku application.

`git push staging staging:master`

This is instructing Git to push your local staging branch into the master branch (heroku only deploys a master branch) of the staging remote (ie robot-6850 application)

More info in [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) on Dev Center